# How to read the password from variable?

Tags: password, command-line, environment-variables, rsync

I am trying to move my file to another system which is located in some other place, with this command:

```
rsync -avrz  src destination
```

It works fine. But what I need is to put this command in shell script and run it like:

```
#! /bin/sh
rsync -avrz  srcfilelocation destination
```

When it runs, it asks for the destination system password. I know that password and give it manually.

Now I have decided to assign the password to an environment variable, like `pswd="destination system password"`. I need my shell script to read the password from this variable. How can I write a script to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to worry about passwords when you can use something called Public Key Infrastructure.

This is a method of using public and private keys to authenticate a user. You store a copy of your private key, and the other server has a copy of your public key. When you log in, they have a little conversation with each other which confirms the public and private keys match so you can log in without entering a password.

This is as secure as anything as long as you don't share your private key with anyone!

To set this up is really simple.

On source machine, run ssh-keygen. You can accept all the defaults, that'll be enough for this purpose. It'll generate your private (id_rsa) and public(id_rsa.pub) keys in your ~/.ssh folder.

Now you want to get the public key on the server, which is easy too.

From the source pc, run ssh-copy-id username@servername.

This will place a copy of id_rsa.pub's content in the server's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.

Now if you ssh from the source to the destination you will get in without requiring a password.

How does this affect rsync I hear you ask? Rsync uses ssh!

Please remember: NEVER GIVE OUT YOUR PRIVATE KEY (id_rsa) or someone can pretend to be you.

Comment: Its not work in my ubuntu 10.04 system. After did all the above steps, since it ask password.

Answer (score 1):

I do recommend using PKI/SSH keys over doing this but if you need to you can set an environment variable like so:

```
export RSYNC_PASSWORD="yourPasswordHere"
```

Please note that this does have some potential security implications and will only be available in the current session.

To add this to a user's session by default:

```
echo 'export RSYNC_PASSWORD="yourPasswordHere"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Alternatively, you can use a password file to store your password. Please note that the password is in plain text, so you should take steps to protect it.

```
echo "yourPasswordHere" > yourPasswordFile.txt
rsync -avrz --password-file yourPasswordFile.txt src dest
```