# How to use rsync from within a python script?

Tags: python, command-line, rsync

I plan to move file from one system to another system. For this, I am using rsync command in linux terminal. It works fine. But I need to implement this command to python. I am very new in python, so I don't know the way of defining the rsync command. So please tell the steps to define it. This is my rsync command:

```
rsync -avrz /opt/data/filename root@ip:/opt/data/file
```

I need to implement this command in a python script.

Comment: Is this Ubuntu-specific? If not, it should be migrated to StackOverflow.

Comment: General programming questions that are not specifically related to Ubuntu are off-topic here. You might want to try our friends in [so] for assistance.

Comment: This seems like a programming question **as applied to a system administration task**. For that reason, I'd suggest that it's on-topic here (and a better fit for our site than for Stack Overflow). I do not think we should close this question.

Comment: Very similar to [How to use tee (or generally a system) command in python?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/175159/how-to-use-tee-command-in-python)

Answer (score 14):

```
import os
os.system("rsync -avrz /opt/data/filename root@ip:/opt/data/file")
```

Did you try that?
`os.system` basically allows you to run `bash` commands.

Comment: Please look at the subprocess module instead, where shell support is disabled by default.

Answer (score 4):

As [the answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/159925/58612) to your previous similar question suggests, `rsync` will work just fine as a shell command from within Python **if you use SSH keys to authenticate instead of a password**. If you need further help with how to set up SSH key-based authentication, please edit your question.